# How to apply arguments to String.prototype.format function

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I am trying to google how to apply arguments dynamically to String.prototype.format function but I can't find anything I would understand. The colsEdit array can contain variable amount.

```
if (!String.prototype.format) {
  String.prototype.format = function () {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function (match, number) {
      return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
        ? args[number]
        : match;
    });
  };
}

colsEdit =
[
  { name: 'Amount', text: 'Amount', required: true, type: 'Numeric', value: 0, default: '' },
  { name: 'Date', text: 'Date', required: true, type: 'Date', value: '', default: new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd') },
  { name: 'CostTypeId', text: 'Cost type', required: true, type: 'Select', value: 0, default: 1, dataSource: [] },
  { name: 'CurrencyId', text: 'Currency', required: true, type: 'Select', value: 0, default: 9,  dataSource: [] },
  { name: 'CountryId', text: 'Country', required: true, type: 'Select', value: 0, default: 16, dataSource: [] },
  { name: 'Description', text: 'Description', type: 'Text', value: '', default: '' }
];

var sql = 'insert into MON_Costs (Amount, Date, CostTypeId, CurrencyId, CountryId, Description) values({0}, STRFTIME("%Y-%m-%d", "{1}"), {2}, {3}, {4}, "{5}")';
var args = [];
var id = 1;//just test

for (var i = 0; i < colsEdit.length; i++) {
  args.push($('#__{0}'.format(colsEdit[i].name)).val());
}
args.push(id);

sql = sql.format(); //how to add args to format function???
```

Comment: Why not *not* use `String::format` but call `.replace` manually?

Comment: You should be using `/\{(\d+)\}/g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [`apply` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) of functions:

```
sql = sql.format.apply(sql, args);
```